# Как использовать Asset Database не только в Editor

Tags: c#, unity3d, build

День добрый. Пытаюсь собрать игру, но в процессе поняла, что в скриптах использую UnityEditor (конкретнее - AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath()), а он не работает вне эдитора. Как можно решить эту проблему? Или может есть альтернативный вариант получения пути файла?

Comment: попробуйте конкретизировать, зачем именно вам нужен путь к файлу проекта и что это за файлы

Comment: В папке Ресурсы у меня хранятся текстовые файлы, с которых, грубо говоря, текст выводится на сцену. При сохранении мне было необходимо запоминать, какой файл находится на сцене в данный момент и запоминать его директории внутри Ресурсов, чтобы потом с помощью Resources.Load() во время загрузки находить его.